# MLE for discrete uniform distribution

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, discrete-data, uniform-distribution

I am trying to find $N$ by MLE for several discrete uniform distributions involving a parmeter $N\in \mathbb{Z}$.

- If the interval $X$ is defined on is $X\in (N,N+1,...,N+10)$ then I think $\hat{N}=\min\{X_1,X_2,...X_n\}$
- If the interval is $X \in (N-10,N-9,...,N+10)$ then I think $\hat{N}=\max\{|X_1-10|,|X_2-10|,..., |X_n-10|\}$

Can someone confirm my solution? Or correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Please give the model explicitly, including what values $X$ and $N$ are defined for (or at the least, explicitly state whether the distribution is discrete or continuous -- it looks like it's intended to be discrete but it's better to be plain). Please show your working - how did you get your answers? It's hard to explain where you went wrong if you don't explain your reasoning.

Comment: according to the example you explained to me before, the likelihood function has biggest maximum for the minimum of the sample.That's why I think N^=min{X1,X2,...Xn}... and for the other one use absolute value so my MLE corresponds with negative values from the sample. I use max but I think that is same if i try with min so the difference would be N^=min{|X1+10|,|X2+10|.....|Xn+10|} . Mostly i am not sure about the first one... actually i don't get the given interval. For the second one I am pretty sure.I tried with an example and it seemed okey.

Comment: But it's not the same problem as before! You just appear to be guessing where you should be calculating. I'll give some hints/strategies in an answer.

Comment: I have attempted to clarify your question. Your question should still show the actual attempt (i.e. show *how* you obtained your answers)

Comment: Now i've be thinking is it possible to have more then one MLE for N ?

Comment: Clearly a function can have a maximum at more than one point. Don't focus too much on the maximum yet -- work on understanding how the *likelihood function* behaves (how it relates to the data). Once you can give an explicit form for the possible values $N$ can take (given the data), you're 90% done.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9rp6kz @Glen_b this is an example from the book.What 's the difference with mine interval ?

Comment: Your problem is discrete. Outside of that there's distinct similarities -- as there often is when dealing with the discrete vs the continuous uniform (indeed, I exploited the same similarities to try to give you a sense of what was going on with a different problem involving the discrete uniform on your previous question). There are some differences, and you still should try to produce the argument here without directly following that one. Did you not follow through the steps I gave in my answer already?

Comment: To get your question reopened, you'll likely need to edit to ask specific things about the problems you had with your attempt (see the `self-study` [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)). I think most of the downvotes accrued before my edit, so your question is already somewhat improved, but I can't show your attempts nor ask your specific questions for you. If you do ask specific questions, it would be possible for someone to give more than just the general approach already offered.

Answer (score 2):

Both your answers appear to be incorrect.

Here's a step by step approach to coming to understand what the situation is (I do an abbreviated version of this sort of thing quite often; it helps build intuition which reduces algebraic mistakes; in situations like this one I think it's indispensable -- you should use it on *both* your problems):

- Consider a specific observation, like say $x=20$. What $N$ can give you that? What $N$ cannot?
- Consider which values of your parameter would be ruled out by a particular observed $x_i$ (and conversely, and which values would be consistent with it). That is, generalize from a particular single observation to any value.
- Now consider *two specific values*, say $x_1=23$ and $x_2=21$. What $N$ can give you that? What $N$ cannot?
- Draw the likelihood for this particular sample. (Do not show nonzero likelihood where the likelihood is 0, though I guess the risk of you doing that is lower for this problem)
- Consider which values of your parameter would be ruled out by a particular pair of observed $x_i,x_j$ (and conversely, and which values would be consistent with it). You may freely assume a particular one of them to be the larger if it helps.
- generalize what you now understand to the case of $n$ observations.

Comment: hmmm ... if I use 1/(b-a) then for the given interval 1/(N+10-N+10)=1/20 which is constant.No matter which value I use for N.

Comment: If the sample space is discrete, $1/(b-a)$ for the value of the pmf (where it's non-zero) is [wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error). And it's not quite "no matter which value" because for some $N$ the sample will have 0 probability. Work your way through that sequence of steps carefully. If I seem to be pedantic, that's a fair charge, but that's because if you're not careful, you can go wrong very easily. (For problems like this, it's pretty much the case that you can be a bit of a pedant or you can be wrong. A hand-wave and a 'I know what I mean' won't do.)